# Stored Procedure troubleshooting Execution time

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

There is one Stored procedure. It took 2 minutes to run one day and next day it took almost 10 minutes to run.

There is NO change in code.

So, what could be the general trouble shooting tips to check the stored procedure and it's execution time.

Comment: Have you checked outdated statistics and fragmented indexes?

Comment: Might be better suited for https://dba.stackexchange.com/ since no code has been changed

Comment: As much as I love having [tag:sql] on StackOverflow, I see a lot of the same SQL questions over there. Why is this tag just not moved to dba entirely? I guess we typically get the more basic SQL questions over here.

Comment: There could be multiple things responsible. One may be concurrent users/processing using up resources. Another is poor cardinality estimates causing inefficient query plans. Or, a process that runs fast yesterday but is slow today is also a classic symptom of parameter sniffing. If you have an hour or so, this is a good video (by Brent Ozar) on parameter sniffing: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pd7xqLT_-2k Given that parameter sniffing is also a form of poor cardinality estimation, the video could help you in general troubleshooting procedures too.

Comment: As a SQL developer point of view, what are the things we can check to solve the execution time taken by Stored Procedure

Comment: For SQL performance problems, you need to supply us with: the full query, table *and index* definitions, and share the good and bad query plans via https://brentozar.com/pastetheplan. It is most likely bad statistics and/or parameter sniffing, but without this info we cannot help

Comment: When looking for slow things, I tend to use two tools to start with a) Before running the query/stored procedure, `SET STATISTICS TIME, IO ON`. For each command that runs, it tells you how much data was read, as well as how much time it took. The only problem is that it's formatted horribly, and doesn't directly link back to the SQL - you need to work out which query it was. b) Run the query/SP with 'Include actual execution plan' on - look for which queries took the longest (this works best with recent versions of SSMS which show times and estimates vs actuals).

Answer (score -2):

It could be due to stored procedure parameter sniffing.

I recommend this article [brentozar parameter sniffing](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2013/06/the-elephant-and-the-mouse-or-parameter-sniffing-in-sql-server/) for you understanding.

Answer (score -3):

Since no code is changed. Your database or SQL server has some resource issues.

Comment: As a SQL developer point of view, what are the things we can check to solve the execution time taken by Stored Procedure

Comment: Data has probably changed. This can make statistics go out of date which is a typical reason for a query taking suddenly taking 10 times longer overnight